# Hidden field value is not appearing in query string

Tags: php, javascript, json, hidden-field

I have a javascript method which is doing some calculation. At the end, I want to store it in a hidden field. Here is the method:

```
<script>
function getQuantity(){
 var count = document.getElementById('hidden').value;
 var Quantity=new Array();
 var i=0;
 for(i=0; i<count; i++)
 {
    Quantity[i]=document.getElementById(i).value;
 }
var myJSONQuantity = JSON.stringify(Quantity,'');
alert(myJSONQuantity);

document.qForm.getElementById('hdnQuantityArray').value = myJSONQuantity;
alert(document.qForm.getElementById('hdnQuantityArray').value);
}
</script>
```

I have checked here, everything is working fine. The last alert is printing the correct value.
Here is the form, in which there is a button, for which I want to submit fields on submit through method GET:

```
<form  name="qForm" method="GET" action="CalculateTotal.php">
    <input type="hidden" id="hdnQuantityArray" name="hdnQuantityArray">
    <input type="submit" value="CheckOut" id="CheckOut" name="CheckOut">
</form>
```

My query string shows:

```
http://localhost/blazorange/Customer/CalculateTotal.php?hdnQuantityArray=&CheckOut=Submit
```

I want this `hdnQuantityArray` to have some value in query string.

P.S. this javascript method is called from another form's submit button in the same file. And this form is a PHP form.
Here is the code for the other form's submit button:

```
<input type="submit" value=" Total " id="total" onClick="return getQuantity()">
```

**EDIT:**

```
<table border=1>
    <form id="CartForm">    
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h2> <font color='Grey'>Item Name</font> </h2>
            </td>
            <td>
                        <h2> <font color='Grey'>Item Price</font> </h2>
            </td>
            <td>
                    <h2> <font color='Grey'>Quantity</font> </h2>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?PHP

        /*     Displaying the total and purchased cart's items    */

            $j=0;
            $temp=new Item();
            while(isset($ItemsArray[$j])) {
        ?>
        <tr>
                        <?PHP

                    if (is_string($ItemsArray[$j])) {
                $temp=unserialize($ItemsArray[$j]);
                 }

                $ItemName=$temp->getItemName();
                $Price=$temp->getPrice();
            ?>

            <td>
                <font color='Black'><?PHP echo $ItemName; ?>
            </td>

            <td>
                <font color='Black'><?PHP echo $Price;  ?></font>
            </td>

            <td>
                <input type="text" id="<?PHP echo $j;?>"/> 
            </td>
            </tr>


        <?PHP $j++; }?>


        <table>
            <input type="button" value=" Total " id="total" onClick="getQuantity()">
            <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $j; ?>" id="hidden">

        </form>
    </table>
```

Comment: Use `<input type="button" value=" Total " id="total" onClick="getQuantity()">`

Comment: I wasn't saying that was the only problem

Comment: How should I post the whole HTML? its a bit lengthy. Should I ??

Comment: Just post the entire form.  Post everything that the JS and PHP respond to.

Comment: Check now please. This is the other form's code

Comment: Can you make up some values and fill in the php spots please.  I don't know what the php will put out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`document.getElementById('hidden')`

should be

`document.getElementById('hdnQuantityArray')`

There's no element with an id of "hidden" in the code you posted.

EDIT:

You're saying the JS only runs when the CartForm is submitted? That reloads the page, right? When the page reloads, hdnQuantityArray is empty. So when you submit qForm, there's nothing there, because the page loaded with a blank field, and the JS didn't run again. Does that sound right?

Comment: No, that's another hidden field.

Comment: @asma - Give us the full html then please

Comment: I just want to use this hidden field: `hdnQuantityArray`

Comment: Actually, there are two submit buttons. When the first one is clicked, JS function does its calculation and puts the value in hidden field. And when the other button is clicked, form is redirected. Do you mean that value will get empty when form is submitted?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out this scheme of yours. Does the first form actually submit when the button is clicked? Does the page reload then, or does the javascript run and then nothing else happens?

Comment: That's the problem. The page reloads and hdnQuantityArray is now empty. The JS worked, but it worked on the old page view. It never runs in the newly loaded page view. It's probably better to use PHP to pre fill the hdnQuantityArray value after the first form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be doing this:

```
document.getElementById('hdnQuantityArray').value = myJSONQuantity;
alert(document.getElementById('hdnQuantityArray').value);
```

I eliminated the unnecessary "qform" in the document.getElementById call.

Comment: No, it is fine. Because there are two forms on the page.